# Logarithmic property $x^{\log_b y} = x(\ln y/\ln b)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there a property that says:

$$x^{\log_b y} = x\frac{\ln y}{\ln b},$$
where $b > 1$ is the base, and how do you derive it?

Comment: Not sure I am reading the formatting correctly, but let $b = e$ and $y = e^2$. Then LHS is $x^2$ and RHS is $2x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly,
$$\log_b y = \frac{\ln y}{\ln b}, \quad b > 1,$$
which is a special case of
$$\log_b y = \frac{\log_a y}{\log_a b}.$$
So, in general,
$$x^{\log_b y} = x^{\ln y/\ln b} \ne x\frac{\ln y}{\ln b}.$$

Answer (score 1):

No. This is simply untrue.

[image]

is a common base change formula used in logarithms. In this equation, you saying that

$x^{\log_b y} = x \frac{\ln y}{\ln b}$

However, $\log_b y = \frac{\log_e y}{\log_e b} = \frac{\ln y}{\ln b}$

Zoom in bit if you can't see.

Making the substitution into your equation,

$x^{\log_b y} = x \log_b y$, which is clearly untrue.

Answer (score 0):

Let $b = e$ and $y = e^2$ and you will see that the identity is false. (You get $x^2 = 2x$ which is not true for all $x$.)